# Change in Application entity appId property type

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

According to the [doumentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#serviceprincipal-entity) The appId property type changed from Guid to String. I need to hold this value in DB so I would like to know is there is any limitation on the size of that string? BTW the appId property in the ServicePrincipal entity is still defined in that doc as Guid.

Comment: The Application ID can only be the GUID. If you want to store this value to your DB, you can create string to match it. But you cannot chagne the AppID proerty type from GUID to string.

Comment: In the documentation (Entity and complex type reference - Entity reference->Application Entity->Properties) appears that the appId changed to be Edm.String in version 1.5. Is it correct? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I known, for service principal, the appId can only be the GUID. You can also see the appId in the  [ServicePrincipal Entity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#serviceprincipal-entity).

**About appId for Application Entity**

I’m not 100% sure about this. But according to my understanding, **it is the one property in the Manifest in the Application registration**.

For your scenario, I believe that you want to change the Application ID for the serviceprincipal. So, I think that you still cannot change it from GUID to string directly.